# Execute method in other context

Tags: ruby

How can I call `Test#test` method in `DSL` instance?

```
class DSL
  def initialize(c)
    x = # call c.test in self context
    x == 'dsl_method_content_somethig' # => true
  end
  def dsl_method
    'dsl_method_content'
  end
end

class Test
  def test
    dsl_method + '_something'
  end
end

DSL.new(Test.new)
```

Everything I tried gives me:

```
undefined local variable or method `dsl_method' for #<Test:0x007f8c0a934250> (NameError)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. So far it looks like you want to extend with a module (which has its own issues).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be trying to to include a module? If you just want dsl methods in one place, you can do this:

```
module DSL
  def initialize
    x = test
    x == 'dsl_method_content_somethig' # => true
  end

  def dsl_method
     'dsl_method_content'
  end
end
```

Then in your class you can do:

```
class Test
  include DSL

  def test
    dsl_method + '_something'
  end
end
```

Although calling a method, that is defined in `Test`, from the `DSL` module is a little bit odd. As the module then needs to know implementation details, of every class it is included in.